# Loop error going through directory

Tags: vba, excel, loops, text

I am hoping someone can help... I have the below code which worked an absolute treat all day. Until 16:10 and now suddently decides to pick up a runtime error. on line `Sheet1.Cells(lastRow, 1) = Data`

```
Sub Loopthroughtxtdir()
    Dim Filename As String
    Dim Path As String

    Path = "C:\MK\MasterData\"
    Filename = Dir(Path & "*.txt")

    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
        Dim lastRow As Long
        lastRow = Sheet1.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row
        Do While Len(Filename) > 0
            Dim handle As Integer
            handle = FreeFile
            Open Path & Filename For Input As #handle
            Do Until EOF(handle)
                Line Input #handle, Data
                Sheet1.Cells(lastRow, 1) = Data
                lastRow = lastRow + 1
            Loop
            Close #handle
            Filename = Dir
        Loop
    End With

    MsgBox ("Import Complete")

End Sub
```

Can anyone please assist. I am very confused why this was working. Nothing has changed and now has stopped after several tests.

Comment: What is the runtime error?

Comment: @A.S.H I only get the runtime error when I go into "Immediate" and ?Sheet1.Cells(lastRow, 1) = Data the runtime is 1004 Application-Defined or object-defined error

Comment: just type `?Data` in the immediate window, what do you get? (place first a breakpoint on that line and check the value of `Data` in the immediate window).

Comment: Trying the ?Data I just get a blank line. No respone

Comment: Are you sure you had tested this macro *on the same file* ?

Comment: @A.S.H I have just retried there and it does pull through the first line of the data I am looking to pull through

Comment: Do me a favor for instance and type `Option Explicit` and declare your `Dim Data as String`.

Comment: @A.S.H yes positive I have been working on the tests on the same 5 files all day

Comment: Also check that you dont have any sort of `Data Validation` in your worksheet. Try with a fresh new worksheet.

Comment: @A.S.H Thanks for the advice there. 'Option Explcit' and 'Dim Data As String' done... still no change

Comment: @A.S.H thank you very much. Imported the Macro to a new worksheet and it has gone through fine. So you think Data Validation appears to be the issue?

Comment: Most likely data validation. Probably also some merged cells, these are source of trouble also.

Comment: what's the value of `lastRow` when it errors out?

Comment: Ah great. Thank you for your help much appreciated

Comment: ignore my comment, I saw you already made it

Comment: Lastrow value when it errored out earlier was the last row of the sheet 1048576

Comment: ouch!! you shouldn't use as many rows in a worksheet!

Comment: As I see you're only using the first column of the worksheet. Think of spreading your data across many columns.

Comment: @A.S.H unfortunately our new system is picking up txt files which is why its in 1 column. The system then changes it to a table

Comment: Then keep in mind that you will be limited in the number of rows. `1048576` is the maximum number of rows that Excel can accept *in a single worksheet*.

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out in the comments, you're running out of rows.  One solution would be to test to see if you've just hit the last row, and then continue on a new worksheet (obviously untested, but should give you the gist):

```
Sub Loopthroughtxtdir()
    Dim Filename As String
    Dim Path As String

    Path = "C:\MK\MasterData\"
    Filename = Dir$(Path & "*.txt")

    Dim currentSheet As Worksheet
    Set currentSheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    With currentSheet
        Dim lastRow As Long
        lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row
    End With

    Do While Len(Filename) > 0
        Dim handle As Integer
        handle = FreeFile
        Open Path & Filename For Input As #handle
        Do Until EOF(handle)
            Line Input #handle, Data
            currentSheet.Cells(lastRow, 1) = Data
            lastRow = lastRow + 1
            If lastRow > currentSheet.Rows.Count Then
                Set currentSheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Add
                lastRow = 1
            End If
        Loop
        Close #handle
        Filename = Dir$
    Loop

    MsgBox ("Import Complete")
End Sub
```